# How to store emails and user addresses

Tags: php, security

I am currently working on a PHP MVC driven project in which security is a large priority. I already have the following in place:

- CSRF Form Tokens
- PDO Prepared Statements
- SSL Everywhere
- Input is `Sanitized` Through filter_var
- Passwords Are Hashed using password_hash

I am currently looking into securely storing emails and addresses of our users, but in a way that will allow us to use within a mailing list, and allow us to see the address when we need to ship the product. Can someone point me in the direction I need to head in? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say "storing securely", what do you want to prevent against ?

Comment: In the event of a DB breach i would like to make it a bit more difficult for each email, and mailing address to be read. At the moment both are stored without hashing ( In development, not production )

Comment: You could review all data items to see if you need them. Find out if you really need to store a user's home address, for example (most web apps do not). You could also move things like email addresses to a separate server that needs access to it e.g. for mailings and forgotten passwords. That server could have an API e.g. "send email X to user 123" and thus the web app does not need to know the email address at all.

Comment: I was considering this approach, but became overly concerned with the possibility of a breach in the main api and all sub sites being affected. Once completed this will be used to run several of my projects, until i have a solid grasp on security/api's i will be avoiding this route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than rolling out your own cryptography library, please use one of the existing ones.

I highly recommend this [PHP encryption library by Defuse Security](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) instead of toying with `mcrypt_encrypt()`. (Also, mcrypt is abandonware.)

Comment: I didn't roll out my own. The issue i am having now is searching through db for a specific email when it is encrypted. Is there a way to do this? I have been googling but haven't found anything yet. Also should i be storing the encrypted keys as type varchar with 255 char limit or text?

Comment: PS: This is used for things like already registered email addresses, specific id's, things of that nature.

Comment: I would recommend text fields. When I rolled my own crypto library, an empty string -> 116 characters of ciphertext with the version tag, IV, and MAC. A sufficiently long email address will quickly overrun 255 chars.